# How to get Fluentd HTTP plugin to return data in response body

Tags: api, http, fluentd

I'm trying to create an API using Fluentd that receives events via HTTP, parses those events, and then returns the parsed event data to the client in the response.

I have been able to set up the HTTP endpoint in Fluentd and verify that it is receiving data. However, from the documentation, I cannot find a way to return data to the client in the response body.

I'm starting from the standard HTTP example in the Fluentd docs:

```
<source>
  @type http
  @id input_http
  port 8888
</source>

<match debug.**>
  @type stdout
  @id output_stdout
</match>
```

And when I curl the endpoint

```
curl -i -X POST -d 'json={"json":"message"}' http://localhost:8888/debug.test
```

this is what I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
```

So the endpoint is working, but I need it to return data to the client.

How could I modify my config to return data in the response, in addition to the status code information? Do I need to add an output or can this be accomplished by modifying the input? Obviously I will need to add a parser or exec filter of some type to modify the data before it is returned, but right now, I am just trying to get it to return the request body.

Answer (score 0):

[Fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/) is logs aggregator and collector with inputs, outputs and transformation. It doesn't work as API like you are desiring.